# If I use the memcpy function to copy an array, what possible consequences: bottlenecks and perfomance changes?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, memcpy

I am trying to implement my container Vector for an educational purpose.
While implementing it`s **method reserve** I faced the question:
**that is the best way of relocation of array of elements from one place in memory (initial capacity)
to the memory allocated for a new capacity?**
I consider 2 possibilities: using loop or using c function **memcpy**.
Here is my implementation:

```
template <typename T>
void MyVector<T>::reserve(int elements) 
{
    if (m_size >= elements) // when no need to reserve memory as at least demanded amount of memory has been already allocated
        return;
    m_capacity = elements;
    tmp = m_array;
    // allocate needed amout of memory:
    m_array = new T[elements];
    // copy elements ???? can I use memcpy????
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        m_array[i] = tmp[i];
    }
    delete tmp;
}

template <typename T>
void MyVector<T>::reserve1(int elements) 
{
    if (m_size >= elements) // when no need to reserve memory as at least demanded amount of memory has been already allocated
        return;
    m_capacity = elements;
    tmp = m_array;
    // allocate needed amout of memory:
    m_array = new T[elements];
    // copy elements ???? can I use memcpy????
    memcpy(m_array, tmp, m_size);
    delete [] tmp;
}
```

**Questions:** 
- what bottlenecks should I take into account?
- what difference in performance?
- are there more efficient methods?
- can you advice my a source of info where implementation of STL containers described in depth (my aim is to made my own implementation and when compare with professional implementation in order to check my knowledge and to find out what areas need improvement)

Comment: Just to point is must be `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Comment: you could use std::copy instead of memcpy

Comment: "can you advice my a source of info where implementation of STL containers described in depth" <- Simply have a look at the actual source code?

Comment: @hmjd thanks, I made changes.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland and If I use std::copy that advantages I will get over my methods???

Comment: @us2012 thank you, I just realised that I can look implementation in header of vector due to it is a template. I kept in mind that all source code from STL hidden from client.

Comment: If its about performance you have to measure it. Use a profiler like very sleepy.

Comment: C++11  move semantics would be useful here...

Comment: @spin_eight the advantage of being real C++ and not crappy C :-) I like C but you should to avoid it when there are pure C++ ways to do these things. Profile before optimizing. Though you have the right to wonder about memcpy... that's right also.

Comment: @andre thank you very much for the profiler, formerly I had no idea at all how to assess perfomance of my application, no I have at least one tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `memcpy` because non-trivial objects may contain pointers to other blocks of memory.

Consider a vector of `std::string` : Each is typically implemented as a small object containing a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of chars. If you `memcpy` the strings, you make a copy of the pointers but not of their actual character data. But the *ownership* of those pointers is not transferred. So when you delete the original array (which calls the destructors for all those strings) their memory is freed, and your 'new' objects all have dangling pointers.

Using `std::copy` is a better way of achieving this.

Comment: So if looking at your example : container of strings it shows that my method fails when dealing with objects which have pointers/references as members. Reason that memcopy allows my to perform a shallow copy, not a deep copy. Does std::copy performes deep copy and how it is done(through invokage of copy constructor or move copy constructor)? Since that version of C++ standart std::copy is availiable. If compare loop and std:: copy that is more efficient (proper to use)?

Comment: @spin_eight : std::copy  invokes the assignment operator, not the copy constructor. Your objects are already constructed by `new[]`. Fastest way of doing it? Wouldn't think there's much difference between your loop and `std::copy`. `std::vector` will be much faster for complex objects in C++11.

Comment: std::copy may (if implementation chooses to do so) resolve to a call to memcpy (or something similar) for trivial (POD) objects. So it is in many places is also the correct choice performance wise.

Comment: @spin_eight: You putting "(proper to use)" after "more efficient" is a big mistake. Efficiency is nice, but your primary concern is working, clean code. Nobody cares how efficient your code is until it works. And most efficiency issues solve themselves if you just code for cleanliness. Stop worrying about it.

Comment: @GManNickG I am agree with you, in a project "proper to use" may have higher priority than "efficiency" (especially in C++) so this may allow to spend more time and pay more attention to problem field(proper design...). But my aim was to train my brain trying to implement something efficient and then compare result to the already implemented things, so I did it only for educational purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are performance aspects as well as other factors where copying an object using `memcpy` and "simple loop" method will make a difference. For example:

```
class Blah
{
    Blah()
    {
        some_function(this);
    }
};

MyVector<Blah> v;

...
```

Now, if `some_function` stores `this` in some way [for whatever good or bad reason], your `reserve1` will cause it to be deleted, but the reference to `this` will remain pointing to the deleted object. Which is probably not what you wanted.

The same of course applies if the object contains any object that uses allocation internally - for example `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Roddy. But even worse. Even if you manage to free the old memory without invoking the destructor and the other memory is not freed, some object could contain references or pointers to internal parts, with will be broken anyway.  Finally it would be good to know the consequences of the new memory alignment.(For T=char, memcpy will be probably the best).

**If it works, forcing a move assignment in your `for` can be the best solution.** (you dont need the old copies)

Well, ultimately you can see how the std::vector is designed, with separate memory allocation, uninitialized and then in place initialized, copy or moved. Take a look at 19.4 Allocators, in The C++ Programming Language, Third Edition by Stroustrup.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got the good answer that addressed almost all my concerns. As I am not going to use MyVector only for built-in datatypes I realized that memcpy will be a bad idea